# sshfs with automount failing silently

Tags: mount, automounting, sshfs, autofs

I am attempting to "permanently" mount a network drive (CentOS 7.4) on my local machine (macOS 10.12 Sierra) using `sshfs` and `automount`

First off, **is this actually the most appropriate tool to use** for this? Essentially I want it such that it reconnects every time I open my computer. I've seen other solutions using `/etc/fstab` but I also could not get them to work.

I already have it working with the `sshfs` command from the terminal (so the `sshfs` and FUSE installations should probably be ok)

```
sshfs <user>@<address>:/ /Users/me/Desktop/netwk -o defer_permissions,transform_symlinks,volname=netwk
```

Here's what I've done:
I've set up my `/etc/auto_master` with the following line:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/netwk auto_netwk
```

and created `/etc/auto_netwk` as follows: (are all the colons/slashes in the correct places? I've found a few different variations)

```
netwk -fstype=sshfs ://<user>@<address>:/
```

Now, when I run `sudo automount -vc`, it appears to successfully mount the folder and returns

```
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: /Users/me/Desktop/netwk mounted
automount: no unmounts
```

and `mount` returns

```
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_netwk on /Users/me/Desktop/netwk (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

However, the mounted volume does not appear to have any contents: opening `~/Desktop/netwk` in shows an empty directory, the size reads zero, and `ls ~/Desktop/netwk/netwk` simply hangs.

**Is there an obvious misconfiguration or a step I'm missing?** (I've already looked through all the similar questions here, but they all seem to get a clear error, whereas mine appears to fail silently)